# How do I retrieve data from a textarea?

Tags: flask

I am having trouble retrieving data from a textarea in flask.
The error message I am getting is the following:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'data'
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<textarea name='data' placeholder='some placeholder'></textarea>
```

And here is my python code:

```
text = request.form['data']
```

I have also tried encapsulating the textarea in a  like this but didnt work:

```
<form method="post">
    <textarea name='data' placeholder='some placeholder'></textarea>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show us the code of the function that handles the request.

Comment: @cizario the python function is pretty simple becouse atm I just want to see if it retrieves the text in the textarea correctly. `if request.method == 'POST' (new line) text = request.form['data'] (new line) print(text)`

Comment: the description of your question doesn't bring anything useful to debug it's vague.